# How to make word document from openxml content in c#?

Tags: c#, ms-word

I have a word document and that document contains tables. after iterating tables and rows, i am getting "Content of a table cell" which is an **OpenXml** data.

I need to convert that **OpenXml** data to html.
              OR
How to create an word document using the **OpenXml** data

While i read entire word document data and i am successfully converted to html using **OpenXmlPowerTools**

Please give me any tips for doing the above task
Thanks in Advance

Comment: It is a bit unclear what you already achieved yourself and where you need help. Could you please describe the particular problem you are facing?

Comment: I have a table in word document. when i tried to read a table cell content, i am getting an OpenXML data. i need to convert the OpenXMl data into html.